# Automating a Drop down selection(IE web application using Excel Macro) is not working?

Tags: html, vba, excel

**Working on automating a form filling on IE using Excel macro:**

Am trying to choose a value from a dropdown(Lets call it a DP1), depending upon the value selected here(for instance, DP1 has 8 options and am selecting 5th option), data will be fetched for further dropdowns of the form.

**General Behavior(When we select a value using mouse click):**

1. Initially the word "**select**" is default display of DP1, and all the further dropdowns are blank.
2. On Mouse click, the "**text of option5**" gets displayed on DP1, and webpage will fetch the data for next dropdowns.

Am writing a Macro to simulate the selection of a the value for DP1.

**Expected Result:** Same as General behavior

**Actual result:**

1. Initially the word "select" is default display of DP1.
2. Now, the "text of option5" gets displayed on DP1, but the webpage is not fetching the data for next dropdowns.

**Details of the DP1 as per the HTML code:**

```
    <select name="name1" Class="tb1" id ="DP1" onchange="javascript:getvalues1()" size="1">
<option value="0">----Select-------</option>
<option value="15300">C1</option>
<option value="15301">C2</option>
<option value="15302">C3</option>
<option value="15303">C4</option>
<option value="15304">C5</option>
<option value="15304">C6</option>
<option value="15305">C7</option>
</select>
```

**All the possible things I tried:**

1.I tried changing the value of the Drop down. = It did not work.

```
set selectobjects = ObjIE.document.getElementsByTagName(select)

For Each Selectele In selectobjects 
 If Selectele.name = "name1" Then
  OptionCount = 0
  For Each Optvalue In Selectele
   OptionCount = Optioncount + 1
   If optioncount = 5 then
    Optvalue.Selected = True
   End If
  Next
  Exit For
 End If
Next
```

2.Tried to click it using Sendkeys = It did not work.

3.Tried to lock focus on to the element and press space/left click using send keys with proper wait time =did not work

4.Tried to using Keybd_event and simulated the click of a down arrow after fixing focus on the element = did not work.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfor As Long)

    Private Const VK_DOWN = &H28
    Private Const KEYEVENTIF_KEYUP = &H2

    Call keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0,0,0) 'Press down arrow

    DoEvents
    Application.WAIT Now+TimeValue("00:00:03") ' application will wait for 3 seconds

    Call keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0,KEYEVENTIF_KEYUP,o) 'Release down arrow
    DoEvents
    Application.WAIT Now+TimeValue("00:00:03") ' application will wait for 3 seconds
```

Just for information: I used all these methods of clicking and selecting many times and they work very well. But, only in this case i got struck.

Can some please explain why is this not working when am trying to automate the process(Drop down selection) and the same is working when I click using mouse? Thanks in Advance!!

Please let me know if any further info is needed!

Comment: You need to set the `HTMLElement` value to the _value_ of the option you want -  `<option .... value="1">` _(or similar)_. The option values should be nested in the `<select>` block. You haven't included these in your example so it's hard to provide a working answer.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response!! Please find the updated HTML element information.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
Sub passValueToComboBox1()
   Dim ie  As Object
   Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate "http://your_URL_here.php"
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

   Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByName("selectedReportClass")(0)
   If Not oHTML_Element Is Nothing Then oHTML_Element.Value = "FUBU7"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
   Next
End Sub
```

The easiest thing to do is hit F12 on your keyboard so you can see the HTML behind the page.  Identify the ComboBox by name (it will be highlighted when you pass your mouse over the HTML code) or ID (0, 1, 2, etc.).  Then, simply pass the value straight to the ComboBox.

Give it a try and see how it goes.

Finally, if F12 doesn't do anything, download and install the IE toolbar.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32987